# Trying to write a simple alphabet program with php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Im trying to spit out each letter of the alphabet from an array on a single line, A-Z.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
$alphabet = array ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

while ($alphabet) {
   echo $alphabet;
   $alphabet;
}
```

Im kinda stuck at this part and not quite sure what else to write to make this work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your loop does not work as expected because you are not looping over the array. You are just evaluating `$alphabet` which evaluates to `true`. You have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$alphabet = array ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

foreach($alphabet as $letter) {
echo $letter;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
function e($s) { echo $s; }
array_walk(range('A', 'Z'), 'e');
```

Working example: http://codepad.org/pedjOlY9

Comment: thanks for your working code.  As im just learning php, is it possible to say the same thing using a while loop instead of foreach?

Comment: @WillingLearner: Of course you can do it. Every loop can be turned into a while loop as it is the most basic loop. But you'd have to code more and it gets less readable. Always go with the solution that it easiest to understand. `foreach` is easy, because the name already implies that something is done for each element of something else.

Comment: @Felix I really don't like it when the correct answer isn't the accepted one. :(

Comment: they both work, but i accepted the other one because it was just a slight tweak on what i already wrote. Im trying very hard as a novice to learn php, so i dont want to jump ahead of myself here and get into more elaborate setups just yet.  Still getting my fundamentals down.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need the array...
This is why we have the ASCII code.
You can do is like this:

```
for ($i = 65; $i <=90; $i++)
{
    echo chr($i) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

chr() displays the character in the ASCII map - check it here: http://www.danshort.com/ASCIImap/. If you want to do lowercase - just use strtolower() or the numbers between 97-122 instead. PHP_EOL is a built in constant that outputs end of line. You can change it with ."
" if you are doing HTML.

I think range is a little bit longer to be done, but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

This might be help full for you

```
$alphabet = array ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

$c = sizeof($alphabet);    
for($i= 0; $i < $c ; $i++) {    
    echo $alphabet[$i];    
}
```

and you can use count($alphabet) instead of sizeof() built-in function